# I want to run Ubuntu with a split partition for windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu, portable

I'm running win10 4g ram 64bit on a lenovo desktop, hooked up with a 2tb portable hard drive. I just heard about lubuntu, and I've used puppy Linux about 20 years ago.

suggestions? Microsoft and Google have me at my wits end. Is my system big enough? Could I install and run Ubuntu on the portable?

thanks for helping me out. I did some computer programming in 1978, and enjoyed playing inside Win95, but things have changed in the decades since.

Comment: I used devices that had IBM on them for testing Lubuntu & Xubuntu releases up to 19.04 (or the 2019-April release); ie. devices incapable of running windows 10 before Lenovo purchased the plant. I'm using a 2009 dell & running the current Lubuntu *development* release (what will be 22.10 on release) so your device will likely run it, as all Ubuntu *flavors* & main Ubuntu will too. As for what's best; it's more than just hardware in my opinion, as the apps you'll use can decide what's best for you, plus your tastes (*what makes you happy*). That is *opinion* which is off-topic on this Q&A site.

Comment: FYI: If you want a Forum, try https://ubuntuforums.org/ which allows *opinion* geared questions in contrast to this *Question & Answer* specific. I'll happily talk about Lubuntu, but we're off-topic here on this site.  Be aware though that a search for "Lubuntu" on a search engine will bring up *fan*, *fake* & the legitimate web site, so if unsure - don't use *google* (unless you can pick up what's real, *fake* or *fan*) and go through [ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) which is curated by Canonical/Ubuntu thus is correct for anything Ubuntu related.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu to any *block device* you want to, however your machine must be able to boot from it for it to actually work. In my experience, the device firmware & settings is what matters here most (*just as it did 20-30 years ago*). You gave no release details; but I've booted & installer Lubuntu to thumb-drives, external drives having no issues on some hardware, but it was a *royal pain* (*install stage*) on others.. but once created it was easy to use on almost all. Some releases easier than others too; and you're devoid of specifics. This ~applies to all *flavors* of Ubuntu too